# AngularJS: Auto-update the totalPrice value

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm in progress of my first simple app, I have experienced many problems already and this one is just the next problem in this long serie.

I have to let the user choose the quantity of each product. There were few ways to do it, I chose that one, in which the user chooses the product he wants, and then - on the shopping list - he can adjust the amount of the product as he wishes. I don't know if its a proper way, but like I said this is my first ap and I've started learning AngularJS yesterday.

I have to combine somehow the:
`total += $scope.itemsToBuy[i].price * TheQuantityOfEachElem;`

I've already tried, but failed miserably. This is how it is when you start something...

**My first idea** is to take the value of the nth input and then multiply it with the price of elem. But the problem is that I don't know how to set this combination.

Sorry for such a long story, if you have any ideas, proposals or hints just let me know. I will appreciate it as always. Thank you in advance.

**The jsfiddle of my app so far**: https://jsfiddle.net/scgsc7or/14/

The totalPrice works, but it doesn't include the quantity.

Comment: Attach a callback to the buttons that updates the total on clicks.

Answer (score 5):

[@mark](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7050130/mark-adelsberger) is right. But if you do this at first it will give **NaN** in total price as quantity is not defined when you add a item in cart.

Either add 1 in quantity or use below code:

`total += $scope.itemsToBuy[i].price * ($scope.itemsToBuy[i].quantity?$scope.itemsToBuy[i].quantity:1);`

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the quantity up/down buttons are updating `itemsToBuy[i].qty`, right?  So what's wrong with

```
total += $scope.itemsToBuy[i].price * $scope.itemsToBuy[i].qty;
```

or something like that when calculating the total price?  (You may have to make sure qty is initialized properly when adding an element to itemsToBuy)